# exploding list-columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following example

```
dftest = pd.DataFrame({'mylist1' : [['hello', 'hasta'], 'one'],
                       'mylist2' : [['there', 'la vista'], 'shot']})

dftest
Out[240]: 
          mylist1            mylist2
0  [hello, hasta]  [there, la vista]
1             one               shot
```

I would like to explode the two columns so that the nth element in `mylist1` is concatenated to the nth element in `mylist2`. `Mylist1` and `mylist2` always have the same number of elements (in this example: 2 in the first obs, 1 in the second obs).

The desired output is shown below. As you can see `hello` is matched with `there`, `hasta` is matched with `la vista`, etc. We obtain three rows because there are two elements in the first list, and just one in the second one.

```
Out[241]: 
         exploded
0     hello there
1  hasta la vista
2        one shot
```

How can I do this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way:

1. `Explode` the dataframe `vertically`
2. `join` strings along axis `1`.

```
df = df.apply(pd.Series.explode).apply(' '.join, 1)
```

##### OUTPUT:

```
0       hello there
0    hasta la vista
1          one shot
dtype: object
```